# How can I Clip curves properly in Plot and ListLinePlot?

Tags: plotting

In my code, I would like to keep these options fixed

```
PlotRangePadding -> None, 
PlotRangeClipping -> False, 
ImagePadding -> 80
```

So, using `Plot` I could clip the curves nicely along X-axis using `RegionFunction` but not along Y-axis. How can I fix that?

```
Plot[
 {x, -4 x}, {x, -5, 5}, 
 PlotStyle -> {
   Directive[Thickness[0.01], Red, CapForm["Butt"]], 
   Directive[Thickness[0.01], Blue, CapForm["Butt"]]
 }, 
 PlotRange -> {{-1, 0}, {-3, 3}}, 
 Frame -> True, 
 PlotLegends -> 
  Placed[
   LineLegend[{"Y1", "Y2"}, LegendLayout -> {"Row", 1}, LegendMarkerSize -> 20],
   {{0.5, 0.5}, {0, -4.6}}
  ], 
 PlotRangePadding -> None, 
 PlotRangeClipping -> False, 
 ImagePadding -> 80,
 RegionFunction -> (-1 <= # <= 0 &),    
 ImageSize -> 600
]
```

[image]

Then I have data and need to use `ListLinePlot` with the same options but did clipping does not work at all now?

```
ListLinePlot[
 {Table[{x, x}, {x, -5, 5, 0.1}], 
  Table[{x, -4 x}, {x, -5, 5, 0.1}]}, 
 PlotStyle -> {
   Directive[Thickness[0.01], Red, CapForm["Butt"]], 
   Directive[Thickness[0.01], Blue, CapForm["Butt"]]
 }, 
 PlotRange -> {{-1, 0}, {-3, 3}}, 
 Frame -> True, 
 PlotLegends -> 
  Placed[
   LineLegend[{"Y1", "Y2"}, LegendLayout -> {"Row", 1},  LegendMarkerSize -> 20], 
   {{0.5, 0.5}, {0, -4.6}}
  ], 
 PlotRangePadding -> None, 
 PlotRangeClipping -> False, 
 ImagePadding -> 80,
 RegionFunction -> (-1 <= # <= 0 &), 
 ImageSize -> 600
]
```

### [image]

**Update 1**

As @Daniel Huber mentioned, the problem can be perfectly solved if I set `PlotRangeClipping -> True`, however, I lose control over the legend position. using Placed[....,  {{0.5, 0.5}, {0, -4.6}}] allows me to precisely move the legend position at any point which is possible with `PlotRangeClipping -> False`. For example, in the case of `ListLinePlot`

```
ListLinePlot[{Table[{x, x}, {x, -5, 5, 0.1}], 
  Table[{x, -4 x}, {x, -5, 5, 0.1}]}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Directive[Thickness[0.01], Red, CapForm["Butt"]], 
   Directive[Thickness[0.01], Blue, CapForm["Butt"]]}, 
 PlotRange -> {{-1, 0}, {-3, 3}}, Frame -> True, 
 PlotLegends -> 
  Placed[LineLegend[{"Y1", "Y2"}, LegendLayout -> {"Row", 1}, 
    LegendMarkerSize -> 20], Above], PlotRangePadding -> None, 
 PlotRangeClipping -> True, ImagePadding -> 80, ImageSize -> 600]
```

[image]

this gives the desired clip but how can I precisely align the legend inside the green rectangle?

**Update 2**

As suggested by @CA Trevillian to use `Legended`. The problem is that legend disappear at the corner and can not be viewed outside the Frame

```
Legended[ListLinePlot[{Table[{x, x}, {x, -5, 5, 0.1}], 
   Table[{x, -4 x}, {x, -5, 5, 0.1}]}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Directive[Thickness[0.01], Red, CapForm["Butt"]], 
    Directive[Thickness[0.01], Blue, CapForm["Butt"]]}, 
  PlotRange -> {{-1, 0}, {-3, 3}}, Frame -> True, 
  PlotRangePadding -> None, PlotRangeClipping -> True, 
  ImagePadding -> 80, ImageSize -> 600], 
 Placed[{LineLegend[{Directive[Thick, Red], 
     Directive[Thick, Blue]}, {"Y1", "Y2"}]}, {{0.5, 
    0.5}, {-2.3, -2.2}}]]
```

[image]

Comment: `RegionFunction` is not a valid option for `List(Line)Plot`. Doesn't it get highlighted in red in the code in your notebook?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update:** Using the options `PlotRangeClipping -> True` and `ClippingStyle -> None` gives the desired result:

```
Plot[{x, -4 x}, {x, -5, 5}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Directive[Thickness[0.01], Red, CapForm["Butt"]], 
   Directive[Thickness[0.01], Blue, CapForm["Butt"]]}, 
 PlotRange -> {{-1, 0}, {-3, 3}}, 
 Frame -> True, 
 ImagePadding -> 80, 
 PlotLegends -> 
  Placed[LineLegend[{"Y1", "Y2"}, LegendLayout -> {"Row", 1}, 
    LegendMarkerSize -> 20], {{2/3, 1}, {.25, 2.5}}], 
 PlotRangePadding -> None, 
 PlotRangeClipping -> True, 
 ClippingStyle -> False, 
 RegionFunction -> (-1 <= # <= 0 &), 
 ImageSize -> 600]
```

[image]

As noted by @valarmorghulis in comments, we can remove the options ``PlotRangeClipping -> True`and`ClippingStyle -> None`to get the same output (since these are default options for`Plot`and`ListLinePlot`).

**Original answer:**

```
plot1 = Plot[{x, -4 x}, {x, -5, 5}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Directive[Thickness[0.01], Red, CapForm["Butt"]], 
    Directive[Thickness[0.01], Blue, CapForm["Butt"]]}, 
  PlotRange -> {{-1, 0}, {-3, 3}},
  Frame -> True, 
  ImagePadding -> 80, 
  PlotLegends -> 
   Placed[LineLegend[{"Y1", "Y2"}, LegendLayout -> {"Row", 1}, 
     LegendMarkerSize -> 20], {{0.5, 1}, {0, 2.5}}], 
  PlotRangePadding -> None, 
  PlotRangeClipping -> False, 
  RegionFunction -> (-1 <= # <= 0 &), 
  ImageSize -> 600]
```

[image]

```
MapAt[Show[#, PlotRangeClipping -> True] &, plot1, {1}]
```

[image]

Comment: that is brilliant, Thanks, Man. Just one question please: these two choices in `Placed` give the same location 1. `Placed[LineLegend[{"Y1", "Y2"}, LegendLayout -> {"Row", 1}, LegendMarkerSize -> 20], {{0.5, 1}, {-0.74, 2.4}}]`  2. `Placed[LineLegend[{"Y1", "Y2"}, LegendLayout -> {"Row", 1}, LegendMarkerSize -> 20], {{0.5, 0.5}, {-1.2, -4.2}}]`  but when apply your approach the second legend does not appear. can you please explain this? I notice that you also change this points even though it gives the same location.

Comment: @valarmorghulis, not sure why it is happening.

Comment: I just notice that only the right choice of points in `Placed` is matters. So, this works too without the options `PlotRangeClipping -> True, 
 ClippingStyle -> False` but don't know what is happening `Plot[{x, -4 x}, {x, -5, 5}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Directive[Thickness[0.01], Red, CapForm["Butt"]], 
   Directive[Thickness[0.01], Blue, CapForm["Butt"]]}, 
 PlotRange -> {{-1, 0}, {-3, 3}}, Frame -> True, ImagePadding -> 80, 
 PlotLegends -> 
  Placed[LineLegend[{"Y1", "Y2"}, LegendLayout -> {"Row", 1}, 
    LegendMarkerSize -> 20], {{2/3, 1}, {1/4, 5/2}}], 
 ImageSize -> 600]`

Comment: @valarmorghulis, you are right. `PlotRangeClipping -> True` and `ClippingStyle -> None` are default values for `Plot` options; so they are not really needed.

Answer (score 2):

This regards the "ListPlot" question. I do not understand why you set `PlotRangeClipping -> False` and then complain about the clipping is not working.

Anyway, you can do what you want by by selecting only those data points in range. E.g.:

```
ListLinePlot[{Select[
   Table[{x, x}, {x, -5, 5, 0.1}], -1 <= #[[1]] <= 0 &], 
  Select[Table[{x, -4 x}, {x, -5, 5, 0.1}], -1 <= #[[1]] <= 0 &]}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Directive[Thickness[0.01], Red, CapForm["Butt"]], 
   Directive[Thickness[0.01], Blue, CapForm["Butt"]]}, 
 PlotRange -> {{-1, 0}, {-3, 3}}, Frame -> True, 
 PlotLegends -> 
  Placed[LineLegend[{"Y1", "Y2"}, LegendLayout -> {"Row", 1}, 
    LegendMarkerSize -> 20], {{0.5, 0.5}, {0, -4.6}}], 
 PlotRangePadding -> None, PlotRangeClipping -> False, 
 ImagePadding -> 80, ImageSize -> 600]
```

[image]

Comment: I set `PlotRangeClipping -> False` to gain precise control on the legend such that I can put it at any point not just at any random location using `Above` or `Right`

Comment: @valar morghulis you might try using something like `Legended` instead, to overcome such a limitation.

Comment: @CA Trevillian, kindly see my update 1

Comment: @valar morghulis your update does not mention any attempt to use `Legended`. I recommend investigating this function to see if it can solve your problem!

Comment: @CA Trevillian, kindly see update 2.

Answer (score 0):

This might be too long for a comment so I will share my finding as an answer

According to the detailed answer by @kglr there are different ways to get the desired clipping.

My problem was that I would like to put the legend at a specific position outside the `Frame` which requires me to use the option `PlotRangeClipping -> False` and this caused the mess in the clipping.  I found out that we can place the legend outside the `Frame` with keeping `PlotRangeClipping -> True` by choosing the correct points in `Placed` as follows

```
Plot[{x, -4 x}, {x, -5, 5}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Directive[Thickness[0.01], Red, CapForm["Butt"]], 
   Directive[Thickness[0.01], Blue, CapForm["Butt"]]}, 
 PlotRange -> {{-1, 0}, {-3, 3}}, Frame -> True, ImagePadding -> 80, 
 PlotLegends -> 
  Placed[LineLegend[{"Y1", "Y2"}, LegendLayout -> {"Row", 1}, 
    LegendMarkerSize -> 20], {{2/3, 1}, {1/4, 5/2}}], 
 ImageSize -> 600]
```

For example, if we replace the points in `Placed` by `{{0.5, 0.5}, {-1.2, -4.2}}` it still gives the correct legend position but to appear outside the Frame I need to use the option `PlotRangeClipping -> False`, I don't understand what is happening but changing these points makes it work!

The last thing is the discrepancy when export as png or pdf. For png it is perfectly clipped

[image]